# Connecting Flow with Business Central On-Prem

Tags: web-services, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-business-central

I am trying to connect Business Central On-Prem (on my local machine where I do the development) with Flow.
I carefully followed all the steps mentioned in http://www.fajdiga.info/blog/2018/11/05/integrate-business-central-on-prem-with-flow/
However, at the stage where I have to put the 
-Web Service URL
-Username
-Password
I get an error `'desktop-pjd3o2q' clientRequestId: b12f58f2-2bf8-4ed1-a56b`

In the Web Service URL I am adding `desktop-pjd3o2q:7048/.../ODataV4`
In Username the `DESKTOP-PJD3O2Q\John Doe`
In Password the Web Service Access Key that belongs to this above specified user.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks a lot in advance for guiding.

Answer (score 0):

If you want use the Web Service Access Key, you have to use the Username of Business Central not Windows Login Name.